# How to set a property for all sets in xmgrace in a single statement

Tags: batch-processing, xmgrace

Suppose I have `file1.dat` and `file2.dat`. I want to plot them and, for both sets, set the line-width of to 2 (for error-bars too) and the symbol to a circle. Currently, I invoke

```
xmgrace -batch batch.xmg
```

with this `batch.xmg`:

```
READ XYDY "file1.dat"
READ XYDY "file2.dat"

S0 LINEWIDTH 2
S0 SYMBOL 1
S0 ERRORBAR LINEWIDTH 2
S0 ERRORBAR RISER LINEWIDTH 2

S1 LINEWIDTH 2
S1 SYMBOL 1
S1 ERRORBAR LINEWIDTH 2
S1 ERRORBAR RISER LINEWIDTH 2
```

It works as expected, however `batch.xmg` becomes big and very repetitive as the number of data files (and, consequently, sets) increases. Besides, whenever I want to modify a common property, I have to go through all sets and change the corresponding value (or to employ a text-processing tool such as `sed`).

Then, I ask: Is there any way to make a global statement that sets a property for all sets? For example, something like

```
SETS SYMBOL 1
```

I thought that statement would work [according to this manual](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/commands.html#sets), but it does not. Xmgrace raises an error and draws no symbol for all sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had overlooked the [Defaults section](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/commands.html#defaults). These statements are available:

```
DEFAULT LINESTYLE number
DEFAULT LINEWIDTH number
DEFAULT COLOR number
DEFAULT CHAR SIZE number
DEFAULT FONT number
DEFAULT SYMBOL SIZE number
DEFAULT SFORMAT number
```

I found out that **you need to write them before the read statements** if you want the defaults to apply to them. For example, this will set the line-width and line-style for `file2.dat`, but not for `file1.dat`:

```
READ XYDY "file1.dat"

DEFAULT LINEWIDTH 3
DEFAULT LINESTYLE 3

READ XYDY "file2.dat"
```

However, notice that, unfortunately, not all properties are available (for instance, you can't set `DEFAULT SYMBOL 1`).